# Android Espresso. How check subtext color in textView?

Tags: android-espresso

I has fragment with textView. I test this fragment by Espresso.
Suppose I has textView with text:

***Hello*, how are you?**

Word "**Hello**" has color **cyan** (#00FFFF). Rest text has color **white** (#FFFFFF).

Here my strings.xml

```
<string name="hello"><![CDATA[<font color=#00FFFF>Hello</font>, how are you]]></string>
```

How by Espresso I can test that ONLY word "***Hello***" has cyan color?

Here how I set text to textView:

```
String hello_text = getResources().getString(R.string.expand_circle_contacts);
textView.setText(MyUtil.fromHtml(hello_text));

public static Spanned fromHtml(String source) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return Html.fromHtml(source, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            return Html.fromHtml(source);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how are you setting that string to your textview? By using `setText(Html.fromHtml(helloString));` ?

Comment: Yes, by using setText(Html.fromHtml(helloString))